# Laravel 5.1 Eager loading when foreign key is nullable?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

I have tables like this:

```
Account(...)
Country(...)
Region(...)
Station(id, name, lat, lng, ...)
Route(id, name, description, account_id, country_id, region_id, ...)
Trace(id, route_id, length, direction, t1, t2, ...)
TraceNode(id, lat, lng, route_id, trace_id, station_id)
```

TraceNode.station_id can be nullable.

When I fetch route object, I want to load as much as possible information, all traces, all trace nodes ...

```
$route = Route::with(array('account', 'account.country','country', 'region', 'traces', 'traces.nodes', 'traces.nodes.station'))->findOrFail($request->input('id'));
```

But I get exception telling me that function addEagerConstraint() fails because object is null (station_id is null in this case).

The way I do this now is:

```
$route = Route::with(array('account', 'account.country','country', 'region', 'traces', 'traces.nodes'))->findOrFail($request->input('id'));

foreach($route->traces as $trace)
    foreach($trace->nodes as $node)
        if( $node->isStation() )
            $node->load('station');
```

How can I tell laravel to skip those trace nodes where station_id is NULL?

Comment: What does isStation() method do?

Comment: ```return !is_null($this->station_id)```

Comment: Does it give the error if you comment the foreach loops?

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I am trying to load all at once, rather than looping trough each node and see whether is it station or not and load it. My current solution with foreach loops works fine, but it is ineffective. I would like to do it with one line which would result in less queries (I guess?).